# No desktop preferences in LXDE

Tags: lxde, lxdm

I'm using LXDE over Ubuntu 16.04.

My issue is that I can change desktop preferences (like center, tile, stretch) from gdm.

But when I login with LXDE, I can't find 'Desktop Preferences' tab/menu anywhere. I tried right clicking the moment I login, but I don't get any option like that.

Well I googled it and found the in lxde, there are two ways to do that:

1. Right click -> Desktop Pref.
2. Menu -> Preferences -> Desktop Pref.

I tried both [now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdtlD.jpg)

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. This is just informational to let you know LXDE security is all on you for 16.04.

Comment: Hey thanks for the information. What kind of security issues can I have? I use it as a personal machine for light purposes (studying+browsing+movies) only. Also I never install any ubuntu updates as it messes up my ubuntu installation so now I use vanilla 16.04

Comment: If you're not online there will be no security issues, if you're back-porting all security upgrades yourself (re-compiling your source code etc) then you'll be covered too. I don't monitor the security flaws detected, and with most LXDE devs/coders having gone (over to LXQt) upstream aren't patching much anyway so security is all on you. You're not that much at risk, but risk is still there (as I mentioned in prior comment, use `ubuntu-support-status` to view the packages that no longer receive patches/security-fixes for.. and rely on you to maintain yourself..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that these preferences can be access via command line.

If you right click on your desktop, and clock on open terminal, you can try these commands:

**Open the preference dialog box**

```
sudo pcmanfm --desktop-pref
```

**One liner to set desktop preference to center**

```
sudo pcmanfm --wallpaper-mode=center
```

Additional information can be found at the pcmanfm man page (pcmanfm is the lxde file manager): https://www.mankier.com/1/pcmanfm

Comment: Hi. Now I'm getting the following error. `The desktop manager isn't active.`

Comment: From the man page it seems that this may help, though I do not use LXDE so I cannot test: **sudo pcmanfm --desktop**

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ShsUzbA

Comment: `pcmanfm --desktop` doesn't seems to work for me. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: I don't see an instance in the screenshot where you tried **sudo pcmanfm --desktop**

Comment: here it is https://imgur.com/a/bHByzHV

Comment: okay something worked! I uninstalled `pcmanfm`, then reinstalled, logged out and back in. Suddenly I'm getting desktop preferences options again. https://imgur.com/a/u6vBO5K I never got it for the past 4 months since I installed LXDE on my machine.